# visual studio 2013 C++ - console output not visible

Tags: visual-c++

Recently i installed visual studio community edition and tried to write small console application. 
Program is getting build successfully. But console window is not getting pop up.

Is there a problem, i installed the visual studio on my System "D" drive.

My code snippet :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

    int main() {
        cout << "Hello world";
        return 0;
    }
```

Kindly help

Comment: Your program probably runs fine.   It runs so fast you don't see it.  Try reading a keystroke so the program waits.   While it is waiting for a keystroke you'll see it.

Comment: @SteveWellens you can also just put a breakpoint on the `return` line.

Comment: @MarkRansom - Right....if you are running under a debugger.

Comment: @SteveWellens if you're running from the command line, you don't get this problem because the console stays open. I took the "getting build successfully" to mean that the program was run from within the IDE.

Comment: cin.get() worked. thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `cin.get()` like so:

```
int main() {
    cout << "Hello world";

    cin.get(); // <- Waits for any key press directed at the console window
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much for your quick help. i tried. but still i am not able to see the console window. Do i need to add any environment variables.

Comment: Start a new project. Select "Win32 console project". Select "Create Empty Project". Create main.cpp file, type contents above (without stdafx.h).